# Disabling HTML validation. How to set 'novalidate' for every form globally?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm wondering if I could do something to disable HTML validation for every form in my application.

Is there any way to do this or I just should add `novalidate` attribute for each form tag?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems the only way is to add `novalidate` attribute to each form using JavaScript/jQuery, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").attr('novalidate', 'novalidate');
});
```

Comment: Awesome, I guessed the correct format because I've seen this style before.  Repeating the attribute key to set a false value.  Seems crummy, the default should be that we have to add 'validate' rather than remove 'novalidate'.