# How to get rid of HTML validation or remove red borders on invalid/required elements

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

I am trying to get rid of HTML validation completely. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17828699) would help if I had all inputs inside some forms. But I don't, as with angularjs I only need a form if I want to know if all fields in some set are valid. Moreover, HTML `form` elements don't stack, so I'm using `ng-form` only.

I actually don't care if the form gets validated or not; I only want to get rid of the red border in Firefox just like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24037577). Is there a way how to style the glowing red to zero size or transparency or whatever? In Firefox I can't see it.

Alternatively, is there a possibility to teach angularjs work with some other attribute name rather than `required`, so that HTML5 doesn't jump in to visually destroy my page?

Comment: So you don't really want to get rid of the validation but the styling of invalid fields?

Comment: @Juhana I definitely don't want HTML5 validation/styling as angularjs does it already (and it's easy to use and customizable both with conditions and styles). I can't do everything I'd want with HTML5 and having my field marked as invalid in two different styles is not an option.

Comment: You could put the attribute `novalidate` on your `form` tag.

Comment: @putvande I don't have a single `<form>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
:invalid {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

[`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ainvalid)

Comment: Is it a vendor-agnostic solution?

Comment: No, it is supported by most major browsers.

Comment: @roland I only need it for Firefox anyway, as elsewhere there's no such glowing problem.

Comment: It's not perfect as it could be hinder me on using `box-shadow` myself. But I'm not using it, so I'm pretty happy with it!

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> Actually, there's a simpler possibility: As I'm using no HTML forms at all and I need some top-level container anyway, it can be a `<form novalidate>` instead of a `<div>`. Too simple to be seen.